# Json.NET - Conditionally serialize

Tags: serialization, json.net, conditional-statements

Is it possible with Json.NET to conditionally serialize an object:

```
class Test
{
     public string Id {get;set;}
     public string Value {get;set;}
     public List<Extension> Extensions {get;set;}
}
```

if only Value is set I would like to get

```
{ "Test": "fromvalue" }
```

if Id or Extension is set:

```
"Test": {
     "Id": "1",
     "Value": "fromvalue",
     "Extensions": [ {...}, {...}]
}
```

or even:

```
"Test": "fromvalue",
"_Test": {
     "Id": "1",
     "Extensions": [ {...}, {...}]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm ?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at this, but doesn't provide the functionality described in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a [CustomContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomContractResolver.htm) along with [ShouldSerialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) conditional methods. For example,

Rewriting Test Class as,

```
class Test
{

     public string Id {get;set;}
     public string Value {get;set;}
     public List<int> Extensions {get;set;}

     public bool ShouldSerializeId()=> !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) && Extensions == null);
     public bool ShouldSerializeExtensions()=>  !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) && Extensions == null);
}
```

And writing a Custom Contract Resolver as

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public bool UseTypeName { get; }

    public CustomContractResolver(bool useTypeName)
    {
        UseTypeName  = useTypeName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (UseTypeName && property.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(Test.Value)))
            property.PropertyName = property.DeclaringType.Name;

        return property;
    }
}
```

Now you can deserialize your json as

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                            {
                                ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver((!testObject.ShouldSerializeId() && !testObject.ShouldSerializeExtensions()))
                            };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject,serializerSettings);
```

[**Demo Code**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UwbIs1)